# Building an executable application for windows .exe on mac

Tags: python, windows, macos, pyinstaller

I'm trying to build an application written in python, which can run on Windows without the need to install python or associated libraries(standalone), and I want to do that on my mac. I tried Pyinstaller, but it seems to generate files executable only in a platform that is building the application(in this case, osx). 
Is there easy way out like Pyinstaller or do I have to do that in a very complex way? Since I'm not the expert, the latter option might be impossible for me to do.  Would it be more wise just to try to build the app on windows than mac using pyinstaller?

Comment: Look at [cx_freeze](https://anthony-tuininga.github.io/cx_Freeze/)

Comment: thanks for a suggestion, but the documentation says..Freezing for other platforms
cx_Freeze works on Windows, Mac and Linux, but on each platform it only makes an executable that runs on that platform. So if you want to freeze your program for Windows, freeze it on Windows; if you want to run it on Macs, freeze it on a Mac.

Comment: How about using something like virtualbox to make VM's so you can load up an OS and compile your code on it?

Comment: that's what I've said I would try, and I have, it worked fine.:)   I just wanted to know if there's any software or a trick to accomplish what I've asked..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For `pyinstaller`, [they have clearly mentioned](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/FAQ#features) that packaging Windows binaries while running under OS X is **NOT supported**, and recommended to use **[`Wine`](https://www.winehq.org/)** for this.

> **1. Can I package Windows binaries while running under Linux?**
>
> No, this is not supported. Please use Wine for this, PyInstaller runs
> fine in Wine. You may also want to have a look at this thread in the
> mailinglist. In version 1.4 we had build in some support for this, but
> it showed to work only half. It would require some Windows system on
> another partition and would only work for pure Python programs. As
> soon as you want a decent GUI (gtk, qt, wx), you would need to install
> Windows libraries anyhow. So it's much easier to just use Wine.
>
> **2. Can I package Windows binaries while running under OS X?**
>
> No, this is not supported. Please try Wine for this.
>
> **3. Can I package OS X binaries while running under Linux?**
>
> This is currently not possible at all. Sorry! If
> you want to help out, you are very welcome.

Comment: Can I use Windows 10 Docker image (instead of Wine) for this?